# Hive Job not running

Tags: hadoop, hive

Whenever I am running a hive query - select * from table. It is running fine. But when i m trying to run a MR job for query - select count(*) from table. It is failing with the following error -

```
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
java.io.IOException: cannot find dir = hdfs://hostname:9000/tmp in pathToPartitionInfo: [hdfs://hostname:9000/data1/]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getPartitionDescFromPathRecursively(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:298)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getPartitionDescFromPathRecursively(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:260)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getSplits(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:293)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:1051)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1043)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$700(JobClient.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:959)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:912)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:912)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:886)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:447)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:138)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1355)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:945)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:756)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.IOException(cannot find dir = hdfs://hostname:9000/tmp in pathToPartitionInfo: [hdfs://hostname:9000/data1/])'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
```

Comment: select * doesnt run hadoop jobs where as select count(*) does. Did you check your namenode connectivity?

Comment: Normal map -reduce jobs running fine ?

Comment: Ya Normal MR jobs are running fine.

Comment: hostname?? so your machine name is hostname?

Comment: yes the hostname is there

Comment: could you give the output of "show create table [here the table name]" ?